# Effective Java 3: item 31: using <? extends T> for producers, is not applicable for different data structures

Tags: java, treeset, natural-sort

This code from the *Item 31*:

```
public class Union {
    public static <E> Set<E> union(Set<? extends E> s1, Set<? extends E> s2) {
        // Bloch used HashSet, but I want natural ordering and still make freedom of producer type
        Set<E> result = new TreeSet<>(s1);
        result.addAll(s2);
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Integer> integers = new HashSet<>();
        integers.add(1);
        integers.add(3);
        integers.add(5);

        Set<Double> doubles = new HashSet<>();
        doubles.add(2.0);
        doubles.add(4.0);
        doubles.add(6.0);

        Set<Number> numbers = union(integers, doubles);
        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
}
```

Compiles, but gives runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.Double (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.Double are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at java.base/java.lang.Double.compareTo(Double.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:566)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:352)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeSet.addAll(TreeSet.java:312)
    at effectivejava.chapter5.item31.Union.union(Union.java:12)
    at effectivejava.chapter5.item31.Union.main(Union.java:27)
```

The problem seems to be in using `TreeSet` instead of `HashSet`, because there is apparently no natural sort order of types `Number` and `Integer`. But this would make me thing to never use of `TreeSet/TreeMap` in cases where generics are used, because the assumed freedom of types would turn to not work if an operation of the underlying data structure cannot be accomplished (in this case, the operation of sort, because of natural ordering in trees, which uses comparisons operators that could not be used for "any producer type", but only the same type). Is there way in Java to use generics as well as the features of specific data structures at the same time?

Maybe, if I used this `union` method declaration:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> Set<E> union2(
            Set<? extends E> s1, Set<? extends E> s2
    )
```

That would allow me to properly used trees and catch types that does not implement `Comparable` at compile time?

Comment: You're ignoring the requirements of `TreeSet` (properly implemented `Comparable`). You'd see similar "undefined" behavior if you used `HashSet` and your objects didn't properly satisfy its requirement (properly implemented `hashCode`/`equals`).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis but how could you implement interface `Comparable` to generic type `E` (which is used in `union` method)

Comment: You would need to use a specific Comparable implementation.

Comment: @milanHrabos You can add a third parameter in the `union()` method for the `Comparator` to use, when you create the `TreeSet` instance.

Comment: @Progman I would need to see an example of this implementation

Comment: @milanHrabos Add a parameter `Comparator<? super E> comparator` to your `union()` method and then use it in `Set<E> result = new TreeSet<E>(comparator);`.

Answer (score 0):

In the signature

```
<E> Set<E> union(Set<? extends E> s1, Set<? extends E> s2)
```

`s1` and `s2` are of different types. `<? extends E>` and `<? extends E>` do not describe the same type, each wildcard will be bound to a different type at compile time.

Furthermore, `Integer implements Number, Comparable<Integer>` and `Double implements Number, Comparable<Double>`. `Number` does not implement the `Comparable` interface. So constraining `E` to extend `Comparable<E>` won't help either, because there is no such `E` which is valid for both `Integer` and `Double` instances.

Integers and doubles are not comparable with each other, thus cannot be managed within a single `TreeSet` unless you provide a custom `Comparator` implementation at construction time which is able to compare Numbers of any concrete type.

Here would be one such comparator implementation:

```
Comparator<Number> comparator = Comparator.comparingDouble(Number::doubleValue);
```

But of course this means that your method cannot handle arbitrary objects anymore, only objects of classes which implement the `Number` interface. The widest interface of your function that you can provide is a method which takes two collections of `Comparable<T>` instances; but both collections must contain the same types: you cannot compare integers to strings, doubles to lists, nor maps to bigdecimals.